# Android - Determine SMS Text Limit

Tags: java, android, sms

I'm working on a marketing app with sharing (by SMS) feature.
I need to **determine the maximum allowed characters for THE FIRST PART of SMS**. Normally the limit is 160 characters.

When I type something, e.g. "ABC", it becomes:

`3 / 160`

But when I add  `♥`  character, it should become:

`4 / 70`  , instead of `4 / 160`

And this works not only for special characters, but also Chinese character as well. How to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Below is my code so far:

```
mSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SMS);
    mSMS.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            String SMSText = mSMS.getText().toString();
            String SMSLimit = "160";
            SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            ArrayList<String> messageParts = manager.divideMessage(SMSText);
            if(messageParts.size() > 1){
                if(messageParts.get(0).length() <= 70)
                    SMSLimit = "70";
            } mCounter.setText(String.valueOf(SMSText.length()) + " / " + SMSLimit);
        }
    });
```

But this is **WRONG**, because it only works when the SMS limit is reached. I want it to be working when **the special character is inputted**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you should modify your code like this?

I had same situation , and solved like this. :) hope it helps.

```
boolean isASCII(String str){
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        if(str.charAt(i) >= 128)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
   String SMSText = mSMS.getText().toString();
   String SMSLimit = "160";
   SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
   ArrayList<String> messageParts = manager.divideMessage(SMSText);
   if(messageParts.size() > 1){

     String smsStr = messageParts.get(0);
     if(!isASCII(smsStr)) SMSLimit = "70";
   }
   mCounter.setText(String.valueOf(SMSText.length()) + " / " + SMSLimit);
 }
```

**UPDATE**

*Second version is*

```
private static CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder();

boolean isASCII(String str){
   return encoder.canEncode(str);
}
```

I think this also traverses whole string and as you mentioned it's slow.

I think if you want faster performance you need to override `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged` and get what characters are added or deleted by user.
If user deletes all `unicode` characters you can assume that your string is `ASCII`, so won't need to traverse same string on every change, just you need to look at added/deleted characters, that's optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I appreciate your idea. Still, this means looping the whole string everytime the text got changed. I want to avoid looping if possible (for performance reason).

Answer (score 2):

because ♥ is not standard ASCII character and is Unicode!, and each Unicode character is 2 byte, but each ASCII character is 1 byte.
[standard ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: I just added my code. And yes, I realized it is a Unicode character. But checking for a Unicode character means I have to **loop through the whole text everytime the afterTextChanged() method is being called**. Isn't that kind of slow? I need a more effective way to determine SMS Text Limit.